# "Element is no longer attached to DOM" using Semantic UI dropdown in Angular 4

Tags: angular, transition, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have implemented a Menu using the Dropdown in an Angular Component. **Sign out** dropdown item is a router link, so clicking on it cause a redirection on another component. When i do this it returns the following error:

> Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate.  Use silent setting to surpress this warning in production. slide down out

This is as it appear:

[image]

and this is the code

```
<div class="ui right icon dropdown item">
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="../assets/avatar/man-1.svg">
    {{ user.displayName | truncate:18 }}
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="edit icon"></i> Edit Profile</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a class="item" [routerLink]="['/auth/signin']"><i class="sign out icon"></i> Sign out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the component typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './Auth/auth.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'mvd-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /* Initialize the dropdown user menu */
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  }

  get user() {
    return this.auth.currentUser;
  }

}
```

After the redirection, every click on the page cause this error. 
I have noticed that causing the **slide down out** animation on the drop down at least one time (e.g clicking on Edit Profile) fix this issue, and the error disappears.

Comment: Can you show the corresponding angular code ?

Comment: Updated with the component .ts file. I think there is no other valuable code. Tha strange thing is that everything is working but the console return that error!

Answer (score 0):

How is the transtion property set in your **theme.config** file (in folder */src*) ?

Try to change it as default, if it's not already the case :

```
@transition : 'default';
```